# if $\{V_{a_1},V_{a_2},...,V_{a_n}\}$ $\cup \{X\setminus A \}=X $ $\Rightarrow$ $A=\cup^n_{i=1}(A\cap V_{a_i})$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the proof that $X$ is countable compact space iff every infinite subset has at least one limit point. But I don't see how from $\{V_{a_1},V_{a_2},...,V_{a_n}\}$ $\cup \{X\setminus A \} $ we get that $A=\cup^n_{i=1}(A\cap V_{a_i})$

some notation: Let $X$ be a topological space, let $A$ be an infinite subset and $V_a$ an open neighborhood for every  $a\in A$,  then $\{V_a:a\in A\}\cup \{X\setminus A\}$ is a open cover for $X$

We end up here: $\{V_{a_1},V_{a_2},...,V_{a_n}\}$ $\cup \{X\setminus A \} $ is a finite cover for $X$ and my book says $\Rightarrow$ $A=\cup^n_{i=1}(A\cap V_{a_i})$
why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ can only be covered by the $V_{\alpha_i}$ as the only other set in the cover is $X\setminus A$ (we must cover also all points of $A$). That shows the inclusion $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A \cap V_{\alpha_i})$, the other way round is trivial, as all unionants are subsets of $A$ etc.